# reciprocal of a rational Cauchy sequence that do not tend to 0, is a Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, cauchy-sequences

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence of rational numbers that do not tend to zero, showing that $\{\frac{1}{x_n}\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.
I was not able to use the fact that $x_n$ does not tend to 0, so I am not entirely sure whether or not my proof is correct, can someone check for me? thanks

Proof.

Suppse $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, that do not tend to $0$, Claim then there exists $M>0$ such that $|x_n|>M$ for all $n>0$,

Proof of Claim, suppose $x_n>0$ for all $n$, pick $\epsilon=C>0$,where $C<x_{N+1}$ then we have $n>N\implies x_n>x_{N+1}-C>0$, now pick $M=\min\{x_1,\dots , x_{N},x_{N+1}-C\}$ then we have $x_n>C>0$ for all $n$. Similarly done for $x_n<0$ and hence $|x_n|>M>0$ for all $n$.

Now, since $M<|x_n|\implies \frac{1}{|x_n|}<M$

Let $|x_n-x_m| <\frac{\epsilon}{M^2}$, where $n,m>N$ hence we have $|\frac{1}{x_n}-\frac{1}{x_m}|=\frac{|x_n-x_m|}{|x_nx_m|}<\frac{M^2\epsilon}{M^2}=\epsilon$ and hence $\{\frac{1}{x_n}\}$ is Cauchy Sequence.

Comment: If $|x_n| \lt M$, then $|1/x_n|\gt 1/M$. So no, this is not a valid proof .

Comment: Heh, I like your last edit. Listen, you used the fact that $|x_n|$ was bounded above. Can you find a way to get it bounded from below? That should be more useful.

Comment: The inequality in your last line is incorrect. If you want to make a fraction bigger, you can make the top bigger and *the bottom smaller*.

Comment: Try using continuity of the reciprocal function at all nonzero values.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! do you guys think this edited version would work?